# Finding the limit of a function of 2 variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, functions

Hello I am having a hard time understanding this assignment, I need to find the limit for the equation below as it approaches $(0,0)$, but I don't know how to do that, any help is greatly appreciated.

Use polar coordinates to find the limit (if $(r,0)$ are polar coordinates of the point $(x,y)$ with $r\geq 0$ note that $r\to 0^+$ as $(x,y)\to (0, 0)$):

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}.$$

Comment: Do you know how to convert to polar coordinates, as the hint suggests?

Comment: You want to use that $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and that $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, we rewrite the limit and make use of the trig identity $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$ in the denominator:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{r^3\cos^3\theta+r^3\sin^3\theta}{r^2}=\lim_{r\to0}r(\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta)=0$$

Comment: Is it possible to get a comment on what is going on here? :)

Comment: As in, i understand that you are setting r as going against 0, but why are you including cos and sin

Comment: Sure! ;-) The cosine and the sine are because of the conversion into polar coordinates $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.

Comment: No problem! ;-)